# movie clips on iOS

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, mpmovieplayer

Hi all
Im looking to play a movie on an iOS device and found MPMoviePlayerController which works very easily. So i have my movie playing but i dont want any of the video controls to be visible/active. i was looking through the settings and found things like

```
[moviePlayerController setMovieControlMode:MPMovieControlModeHidden];

[moviePlayerController setMovieControlMode:MPMovieControlStyleNone];
```

and while they do remove the on screen control while the movie is playing they are still visible on initial start of movie.
basically just want to play my movie at start of app without any extra overlays of controls at all ever.
any ideas how to do this? 
any help would be appreciated

g

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AVFoundation has the AVPlayerLayer class (it is ios4 only): http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/02_Playback.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010188-CH3-SW4

Answer (score 0):

`moviePlayerController.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;`

`movieControlMode` has been deprecated.

Remember, This way the user won't have access to the controls.

Comment: avplayer ended up being the best option for me but thanks anyway